# Getting "1.#INF00" when calculating the sum 1!/n^1 + 2!/n^2 + ... + n!/n^n

Tags: c

This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, n, f = 1;
    int exp;
    exp = n;
    float div;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    for (c = 1; c <= n; c++) { 
      f = f * c;
      exp = exp * n;
    }

    div = f * 1.0 / exp;
    printf(" %f\n", div);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting `1.#INF00`. Is there any solution to this without using `math.h`?

Comment: Everything in `math.h` can be programmed in C somewhere else, so the answer is Yes.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: You don't set `n` and copy this value to `exp`, which already generates UB. I think your problem is that `exp==0` You should set every variable as soon as you define them, at best define them right before you use them.

Comment: You will cause UB when `n==INT_MAX` because `c` can never be bigger, as soon as `c==n && n==INT_MAX`, you will cause UB when you increment `c`. Also `f=f*c` may overflow which is also UB. Check that `n` is small enough after the `scanf()` and always check the return value of `scanf()`

Comment: Your code attempts to calculates factorial(n)/(n**n), not the sum (you only use the last term).

Comment: Always use compiler warnings, my compiler would warn about some of the problems in your code that may cause your problems.

Answer (score 2):

`n` is used without being intialized at the line `exp = n;`. Using values of uninitialized non-static local variables, which are indeterminate, will invoke *undefined behavior*.

The line `exp = n;` should be after the `scanf` line.

Also note that typical `int` (32-bit long) can only store upto 2,147,483,647. You should use `double` if you want to deal with large `n`.

One more point is that you want to get the sum, so you should calculate the sum.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, n, f = 1;
    int exp;
    double sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    exp = n;
    
    for (c = 1; c <= n; c++) { 

      f = f * c;
      sum += (double)f / exp;
      exp = exp * n;
    }

    printf("sum = %f\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything in math.h can be programmed in C somewhere else, it is not a problem to not use `math.h`.

There are several problems in your code, i pointed them out as comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, n, f = 1;  //only f is initialized, c and n have a indeterminate value
    int exp; //exp is not initialized and indeterminate
    exp = n; //copy a uninitialized (indeterminate) value, which causes UB
    float div; //div is not initialized and indeterminate
    scanf("%d", &n); //return value not checked, n is may still indeterminate

    //value of n not checked, n could be INT_MAX    

    for (c = 1; c <= n; c++) { //if n is INT_MAX, this loop will run into UB when c==INT_MAX and you increment c
       

      f = f * c;  //This calculates the factorial of n, but can cause UB when it overflows
      exp = exp * n; //exp is still indeterminate, and using it is UB
     
      //The sum is not calculated like you wanted
    }

    div = f * 1.0 / exp; //exp is still indeterminate
    
    
    printf(" %f\n", div);
 
    return 0;
}
```

When you enable compiler warnings your compiler will probably warn you about the uninitialized `exp` variable. Enable compiler warnings and change the code till you have no warnings left.

A better approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h> //for INT_MAX and ULONG_MAX
    
int main(void) 
{
    unsigned n=1; //use unsigned since the value will always be positive
    if(scanf("%u",&n)!=1)
    {
        perror("Unable to parse input");
        return 1;
    }
    if(n>=INT_MAX)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"n is too large\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //Initialize exp when we define it
    //moved the initialization to the place we actually need it and not before
    //use a long since the exp can get large
    //same for f
    unsigned long exp=1;
    unsigned long f=1;
    float sum=0; //summation variable to keep track of the sum
    for(unsigned c=1;c<=n;c++)
    {
        if(ULONG_MAX/c<exp) //check for overflow
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"n is too large\n");
            return 1;
        }
        exp = exp * n;
        f = f * c; //This does not overflow when exp*c does not overflow
        sum += f * 1.0 / exp;
    }

    
    printf(" %f\n", sum);
 
    return 0;
}
```